# Does PHP inherit the attribute it extends

Tags: php, object, inheritance

I have the following code

```
<?php

class ingredient {
    private $calories;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->calories = 100;
    }

    public function get_calories() {
        return $this->calories;
    }
}

class flour extends ingredient {
    
    private $texture;

    public function __construct(texture) {
        $this->texture = $texture;
    }

    public function get_texture() {
        return $this->texture;
    }
}

$plain_flour = new flour("Grainy");
```

My question is, does `plain_flour` have the attribute `calories` initialized already? Can I call `get_calories` on `plain_flour`? If no, how can I make it work so flour has the `calories` attribute ready to go and I can use the `get_calories` function

Comment: Not being nasty or anything but did you try it and find out?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes I did (I know its such a simple question), but sometimes I get an error, sometimes I don't. So I am so confused

Comment: @rjdown No, because the constructs of the class inheriting are empty. Mine are not

Comment: Your Flour Constructor parameter is texture should be $texture so that should have generated a PHP Error if you have them enabled.

Comment: Sorry i posted the wrong link, that was for grandparents. Calling the parent constructor is enough. You also have a typo in the child's constructor, missing the $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `$calories` element is part of the `ingredient` class and is a private variable.
To access the variable from the flour class, you can call the parent's `__construct` method.

See this:

```
class ingredient {
    private $calories;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->calories = 100;
    }

    public function get_calories() {
        return $this->calories;
    }
}

class flour extends ingredient {

    private $texture;

    public function __construct($texture) {
        $this->texture = $texture;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_texture() {
        return $this->texture;
    }
}

$plain_flour = new flour("Grainy");

echo $plain_flour->get_calories();
```